# Why is my jQuery script for checking required input fields so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, each, required

I am trying to use jQuery to check for required input fields for browsers that don't reccognise the `required` HTML tag. My jQuery script is as follow.

```
$('div').on('submit', '#myform', function(e){     
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $( ':input[required]').each( function (e) { 
        if ( this.value.trim() == '' ) {
            $('.error').html(this.name + " is required");
            return false;
        }       
    }); 
    $(this).unbind().submit();
 });
```

But it is very slow to load! after I click the submit button for the form, it takes about 5 seconds before the error messahe shows! It seems it is taking some loops. Why is it that? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegated `submit` handler is not bound directly to the form element so you can't unbind the handler that way. You are creating an infinite loop. You should use the `off` method and unbind the handler of the `div` element.

Also note that the returned value of the `each` callback doesn't affect run flow of the wrapper, submit handler. Each function has it's own returned value.

```
$('div').on('submit', '#myform', function(e){     
    var $e = $('.error').empty();
    var $invalids = $(':input[required]').filter( function (e) { 
        var invalid = this.value.trim().length === 0;
        if ( invalid ) {
            $e.append('<p>' + this.name + " is required</p>");
        }
        return invalid;       
    }); 
    if ( $invalids.length ) {
       return false;
    }
    this.submit();
});
```

The `submit` method of `HTMLFormElement` object doesn't trigger jQuery submit handler so there is no need to unbind the handler. If the validation passes the form is submitted normally.

Performance-wise you can also avoid using `:input` selector. From jQuery [`:input` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Because `:input` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:input` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:input` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":input")`.

The [`elements`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) property of the `HTMLFormElement` object returns a [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0) object in HTML5 browsers and a `HTMLCollection` object in HTML4 browsers that contains all the controls of the form element. You could also use this property instead of querying the DOM and use the jQuery `filter` method for filtering `required` fields:

```
 $(this.elements).filter('[required]');
```

Comment: Also, `:input[required]` is very slow selector.

Comment: @Jashwant Yes, good call. If it's still slow, using a faster selector should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `submit()` in last line you create infinite loop.