# why javascript working after 'return false'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a JavaScript validation code for a dynamically adding text boxes, it's showing alert when text boxes having empty values and not stopping there

```
$(document).on('click', '#med_submit', function () {
    $(".medicine_name").each(function (i) {
        var id = this.id;
        var value = $("#" + id).val();

        if (value.trim() == "") {
            alert('Medicine name should not be empty');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $(".medicine_quantity").each(function (i) {
        var id = this.id;
        var value = $("#" + id).val();

        if (value.trim() == "") {
            alert('Quantity name should not be empty');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

this is my script, in `medicine_name` each function there is any one `medicine_name` class textbox is empty then it shows alert message also it's going to the next `medicine_quantity` each function and show that alert too, here i am using return false after athe alert then how this happening, please help me

Comment: [Each function has it's own returned value!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313838/why-is-my-jquery-script-for-checking-required-input-fields-so-slow)

Comment: Show the HTML too, but I believe a `return false` inside the `each()` exits the each early, not the parent function.

Comment: but i want only one alert at a time, but its showing both

Comment: You could replace `.each` with a simple `for` loop and replace the `return` with a `break` statement then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a flag when you show an alert, and bail early if the flag is set.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#med_submit', function() {
  var alertShown = false;

  $(".medicine_name").each(function(i) {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = $("#" + id).val();

    if (value.trim() == "") {
      alert('Medicine name should not be empty');
      alertShown = true;
      return false;
    }

  });
  if (alertShown) return;
  
  $(".medicine_quantity").each(function(i) {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = $("#" + id).val();

    if (value.trim() == "") {
      alert('Quantity name should not be empty');
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

#### Why doesn't `return false;` work?

The reason it isn't enough to `return false;` inside the `.each()` callback function is that all that does is stop processing the rest of the matched elements in the jQuery set.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/#entry-longdesc):

> You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning `false`.

In other words, all it does is make the `.each()` call finish sooner than it normally would.

Regardless of when it finishes, though, the next line of code to execute after the first `.each()` call in your code is the second `.each()` call. It has no knowledge of what happened with the first `.each()` call, so it will start with the first matched element and call the supplied function for it, and then proceed with the rest of the matched elements unless the function returns `false`, when it will stop.

Comment: @askm3 I added an explanation for why it isn't enough, let me know if you are still confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
var blank_found = false;
$(".medicine_name").each(function (i){
   var id=this.id;
   var value=$("#"+id).val();

   if(value.trim()==""){ 
       blank_found=true;
       alert('Medicine name should not be empty');
       return false;
    }
});

if (blank_found){
   return false;
}

$(".medicine_quantity").each(function (i){
   var id=this.id;
   var value=$("#"+id).val();

   if(value.trim()==""){
      alert('Quantity name should not be empty');
      return false;
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one..

```
$(document).on('click','#med_submit',function(){
var isempty=false;
   $(".medicine_name").each(function (i)
                    {
                            var id=this.id;
                            var value=$("#"+id).val();

                            if(value.trim()==""){isempty=true; alert('Medicine name should not be empty'); return false;}

                    });
           $(".medicine_quantity").each(function (i)
                    {
                            var id=this.id;
                            var value=$("#"+id).val();

                            if(value.trim()==""){ isempty=true; alert('Quantity name should not be empty'); return false;}

                    });

if ( isempty==true ) {
       return false;
    }


        });
```